# foreach loop with promise execute API call AFTER the first one is done

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, promise, async-await

```
let array = [1,2,3];
 array.forEach(function(item,index) {
   var data =  fetch('https://reqres.in/api/products/'+item);
   //wait for response after response come then next iterating a loop (first,second,third)
  
});
```

i want to run like

1. first call api
2. wait for response
3. show into html

but currently my script call all three times api without wait for response

**i want to wait for response and after done then called next api** ..like that

Comment: You probably want to use async/await. https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: And you should algo use a `for of` loop or a normal `for` loop. Async/Await functions doesnt work properlly with forEach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async function asyncExample() {
  let array = [1,2,3];
   for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     var data = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/products/'+item);   
   });
}
```

You have to use Async/Await to make the code wait for the API call. Async/await doesn't work properlly with loop's, to avoid problens with that you should use a normal `for` ou a `for of`. More examples: https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/

Answer (score 3):

use for of instead of forEach loop and make promise for request like that

```
var items = [1, 2];
function makeRequest(index) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://reqres.in/api/products/"+index,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        resolve(response);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        reject(error)
    }
 })
})
}

async function runAsync(locations){
  for(let location of locations){
    console.log('value ' + location);
    await makeRequest(location);
  };
}

runAsync(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to syncronize $http calls. Javascript can do that via Promises.

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ resolve("OK");});

let array = [1,2,3];
 array.forEach(function(item,index) {

    promise.then(
        $http.get('https://reqres.in/api/products/'+item)
    ).then(function (response){
        ...
    });
});         

promise.catch(function(response) {
      ...
});
```